# load image once with universal image loader in listview

Tags: android, listview, universal-image-loader

I have a list view and I want to show thumbnail of video in it but everytime I scroll images download again. how can I download images once and show it.
this is my code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if(convertView == null){
        rootView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_video, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.ivThumbnail = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.ivThumbnailVideoAdapter);
        rootView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        rootView = convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder)rootView.getTag();
    }
    imageLoader.displayImage(update.get(position).getThumbnail(), holder.ivThumbnail, option);
    return rootView;
}
```

Comment: how can I enable it and how can use it, because I enabled caching

Comment: so how, you know that it is downloaded again? ... the server can be a problem fx it not reacts on `If-Modified-Since` or other caching related headers

Comment: imageview not show anything until download image again

Comment: sometimes take a while to decode bitmab from disk cache too

Comment: `because I enabled caching` how? i don't see code related to this in your question

Comment: Are you using com.nostra13.universalimageloader? If so you can specify disk cache policies, but be aware that loading cached images take some time too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with UIL the download of the images is configured with **DisplayImageOptions**

For example :

```
mOptionsSimple = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder().resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
                                                                .cacheOnDisc(true)
                                                                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT)
                                                                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
                                                                .build();
```

Here, cacheOnDisc to true saves the image on the disk, not in the cache. When you scroll the image will reload, of course because in listview cells are recycled. But with this option it will reload from the disk if it was already downloaded

You can also/or enable memoryCache BUT be carefull with this one. It can be the cause of OutOfMemoryException if the images are not managed correclty

also **ImageLoaderConfiguration** here is an example :

```
    config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(getApplicationContext()).threadPoolSize(3)
                                                            .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 1)
                                                            .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.FIFO)
                                                            .imageDownloader(new MyImageDownloader(mContext))
                                                            .imageDecoder(new BaseImageDecoder(false))
                                                            .discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir))
                                                            .discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
                                                            .defaultDisplayImageOptions(mOptionsSimple)
                                                            .writeDebugLogs()
                                                            .build();
```

In this last example the discCache is not limited which could be changed if you think it ll take too much space on the disk

Comment: thanks for your code, its work but I surprise because I use cache in memory but it download again. also before I use cache on disk but again it download, but I thinks you use bitmapConfig and it work, am I wrong ?

Comment: when you say "it download again" do you see the trace in the log ? or is it that the image just feel like it's loading ?